# blank firefox window after launching the test script from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, firefox, selenium, selenium-rc

I am running the below test script with Junit4 in eclipse IDE and I get just a blank firefox window. the server is running and there are no pop up blockers or any other firefox processes running when I kick off the test from the eclipse IDE.

(the test runs ok when I run it from the iE browser)

```
package com.resky.tutorials;

import org.junit.*;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

public class MySecondSeleniumTests {

    @Test
    public void initializeSeleniumRCServer() {
        Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "https://74.27.8.1/");
        selenium.start();
        selenium.open("https://74.27.8.1/");
        selenium.close();
        selenium.stop();
   }
}
```

Comment: OK I dont get a blank page anymore but I get the untrusted connection page when the webpage starts
public class MythirteenthSeleniumTests extends SeleneseTestCase {
public void setUp() throws Exception {   setUp("https://7.21.8.9/", "*firefox");

whatdo i need to do for firefox to trust that when Iam running the script from the eclipse IDE after staring the selenium RC from the dos command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure its not the page that you are navigating to that is untrusted (i noticed you are using https, is the certificate correct?

Comment: Yes it was untrusted..I imported the cer again and it was ok. thanks